# A BIRT exception occurred

Tags: report, birt, spagobi

I am running a report in local server. The query I have added works fine in mysql and is fetching data however when I use the same for running the birt report I get an error:

Table User Registration:
 A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
ReferenceError: "Mobile" is not defined.

1. Could you please tell me what is it that it is referring to so can make changes??
2. I have added startdate and enddate as report parameter. However, when I run it on local server. The start date it picks up from used but the end date it is adding itself. Which is strange. As if it is being set default somewhere. Please guide me where to look to correct this.

Thanks!

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but congratulations on asking question number **50.000.000** :)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Damn. I just got 49999999 and thought *nooooo* :D

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Just being pedantic, but you mean making *post* number 50,000,000. Post IDs are shared between questions and answers.

Comment: The 50 millionth question doesn't have an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You have used a a reference that is not defined (obivously).

Long answer: The query is not the problem. This error is mostly caused by column bindings that are not used but still exist in the column bindings list. The binding is propably called "Mobile". Check the bindings of that table, especially their content if script lines are included.

If you do not find anything there, go the long way: open the xml source, search "Mobile" and see if you can relate to a tag that relates to a BIRT function (parameters, breakpoint methods, bindings, computed columns). From there you might find where "Mobile" hides. Hint: Do not just remove any "Mobile" string from the source file, it may severely break your report (simply saving the source can break it with wrong encoding).